# Display soft keyboard automatically on a dialog activity

Tags: java, android, keyboard, dialog, android-activity

I have a simple Activity that uses a `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` in the manifest.

My activity consists of an EditText, 2 Buttons, and a TextView.  It is nothing more than a box for the user to enter in a name and press OK/Cancel.

I just want to focus the EditText and have the soft keyboard automatically show when the Activity is started.  I've read countless posts about this but I just can't seem to get it to work.  When the activity starts the blinking cursor appears in the EditText, but the keyboard won't show until I click inside it.

Here is my Activity:

```
public class Finalize extends Activity {

    private EditText mEditName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.finalize_dialog);

        mEditName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.file_name_edit);
        mEditName.setFocusable(true);
        mEditName.requestFocus();

        mEditName.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {           
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I've also tried this in onCreate:

```
    InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(this.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    mgr.showSoftInput(mEditName, 0);
```

Edit:  My manifest for reference

```
    <activity class=".Finalize"
        android:name=".Finalize"
        android:label="@string/file_name_title"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"        
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible">
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work. Go to your manifest and update your activity line with the `android:windowSoftInputMode` attribute.

```
<activity android:name=".Finalize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible">
    ...
</activity>
```

See the following [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) page for more details on the different parameters that can be passed into this attribute.

I tested the above and it works fine for me. Here is my terribly simple example.
Code:

```
public class DialogActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);        
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:text="@string/hello"    />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_text_test"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
    <activity android:name=".DialogActivity"
              android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using an activity themed as a dialog instead of just throwing up a dialog?

Comment: @user432209 does your testing device have a physical keyboard?

Comment: The reason I am using the dialog theme is because I need a fully custom dialog and it was an easy way to display the content exactly how I want (transparent outside the dialog box).  I already tried a AlertDialog.builder and it does not allow me to use my own Button onClickListeners which I need.

Comment: The emulator I am using displays a keyboard next to it in portrait and landscape mode, but I didn't add keyboard support when creating the emulator.  The soft keyboard shows up when clicking in the box.

Comment: That could be it.  I created an emulator, added the keyboard option, and set it to false.  The soft keyboard appeared correctly as the activity started.

Comment: Bravo! One thing, you can definitely make a dialog and then populate it with a layout and setup all your own handlers. Look into how to use `showDialog(int)`, `onCreateDialog(int)`, and `onPrepareDialog(Dialog)`. Don't forget to accept if you're satisfied ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this its work for me

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                   imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
```